# How to send email to user in angular

Tags: angular

I have a website ,where user can  fill the contact form.i need the detail data filled in form to my email .Guys can any 1 tell how to send email to the user's email when form is submitted in angular.In simple i want the form detail into my email. after filling the contact form.

Comment: Angular is frontend, and sending emails is backend responsibility. That's perhaps the only thing can be answered. Clarify question.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex said, Angular cannot send an email for you. Use your backend or an email service like [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/). They have a free version and instructions to help you set this up.

Good luck!

Comment: well according to ur reference i found this .https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm  but the thing is here u need to mention sender's email, in my system the send can be any1,  how to do tackle this. i'll use java as back-end.

Comment: you need to set up your java script on an endpoint or something that will accept data. when your user clicks submit, you should take the data from the form and send it to that endpoint. you can use an angular2+ event like (click)="sendData(userData)" on a button in your form.